# How to annotate enum using jaxb2-basics-annotate?

Tags: enums, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-basics, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I'm using maven-jaxb2-plugin and jaxb2-basics-annotate plugins to auto generate POJOs from my xsd. I've successfully generated annotations in POJOs. I need to apply an annotation to a method in an enum but cannot figure out how to do it.

xsd has,

```
    <xsd:simpleType name="DeliveryStatus">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveredToTerminal" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveryUncertain" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveryImpossible" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveredToNetwork" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="MessageWaiting" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveryNotificationNotSupported" />
    </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

generated file

```
@XmlType(name = "DeliveryStatus")
@XmlEnum
public enum DeliveryStatus {

@XmlEnumValue("DeliveredToTerminal")
DELIVERED_TO_TERMINAL("DeliveredToTerminal"),
@XmlEnumValue("DeliveryUncertain")
DELIVERY_UNCERTAIN("DeliveryUncertain"),
@XmlEnumValue("DeliveryImpossible")
DELIVERY_IMPOSSIBLE("DeliveryImpossible"),
@XmlEnumValue("MessageWaiting")
MESSAGE_WAITING("MessageWaiting"),
@XmlEnumValue("DeliveredToNetwork")
DELIVERED_TO_NETWORK("DeliveredToNetwork"),
@XmlEnumValue("DeliveryNotificationNotSupported")
DELIVERY_NOTIFICATION_NOT_SUPPORTED("DeliveryNotificationNotSupported");
private final String value;

DeliveryStatus(String v) {
    value = v;
}

public String value() {
    return value;
}

public static DeliveryStatus fromValue(String v) {
    for (DeliveryStatus c: DeliveryStatus.values()) {
        if (c.value.equals(v)) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
}
}
```

What I need is to add JsonValue annotation to value method above.

I tried following and some other tweaksbut in binding.xjb nothing works.

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:simpleType[@name='DeliveryStatus']">
    <annox:annotate target="field">
     <annox:annotateEnum annox:class="org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonValue"/>
    </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Is there something called annotateEnum? Can it work, if so how?

Please help.

Comment: @lexicore hope u might be able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).

Yes, there is an `annotateEnum` customization element (see the [docs](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin)). But it only applies the annotation to the enum class itself, i.e. to `public enum DeliveryStatus {...}`. So this does not solve your problem with `value()`, this can't be annotated at the moment.

Please file an issue here:

- https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/issues

Would be nice to have a test schema here (please send me a PR):

- https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/issues/src/main/resources/schema.xsd

Unfortunately, I can't promise any due date. I think the fastet way you'de gert results is to try to implement it yourself. See this part of the code:

- https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/plugin/annotate/AnnotatePlugin.java#L209-L229

You'd basically need to add `annotateEnumValueMethod` handler similar to how the `annotateEnum` is done. The only tricky part is that you'll need to annotate not the class but the `value()` method, but it's not difficult. I'll be open to PRs here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It's for a simulator code, so I'd just go for a small hack instead of investing much time on it. Aw thanks for your great work! keep it up :)

Comment: @KalhariLiyanagama But please do file an issue. Maybe I'll get to it somewhen. And thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: The `annotateEnumValueMethod` has been implemented by now (thank you, @lexicore !), but I can't get it to work for the use case, described in this question. I have tried:
`<annox:annotateEnumValueMethod>@JsonValue</annox:annotateEnumValueMethod>
<annox:annotateEnumValueMethod>@org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonValue</annox:annotateEnumValueMethod>
<annox:annotateEnumValueMethod>@com.fasterxml.jackson.core.annotate.JsonValue</annox:annotateEnumValueMethod>`
but nothing works.
@lexicore, can you please give me an advice? Thank you!

Comment: @PavelA Please send me a PR with the reproducing project here: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin-support as `e/enumValue`. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It's a closed-source project, so I'll try to create a simple one to illustrate the issue and then send a PR.

Comment: @lexicore, the PR has been created. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelA Thank you for the PR. I've fixed [your project](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin-support/tree/master/e/enumValue). Updated a couple of versions and added `jackson-annotations` to the classpath of the [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin]. Worked for me, I get `@JsonValue public String value() { return value; }` generated.

Comment: Thank you very much, @lexicore! I'm complete newbie in maven, so guessed the issue is in pom.xml, but couldn't get it exactly right.